# How to decrease the size of a button?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

How to decrease the size of a button?

I have a button in which it contains an image.But my problem here is i am unable to decrease the width of the button along with image.

How can we decrease the size of that kind of button.

If possible provide me some sample code.

Below is my sample code:

```
 <mx:Button id="line" toggle="true" paddingLeft="1" paddingRight="1" icon="@Embed(source='Images/line.png')" toolTip="Line" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" click="doDrawEnable()" ></mx:Button>
```

Thanks,
Naveen.

Comment: "Below is my sample code:"   
Where?

Comment: @snote it was there; just not formatted as code.  @user737830 Be sure to highlight your code segment and click that "curly bracket" Button when posting.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to Use the width property:

```
 <mx:Button id="line" width="100" />
```

This code, for example, would force your button to 100 pixels wide.

Comment: Just to add to Flextra's comment, I've found that for images that are 16x16, you want to set the button's width and height to 22.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `width` property ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decrease the image in the button too, it might be better to use the scaleX property instead of width.